# FPGA patching existing program

Tags: fpga, programming, lattice, hacking

This may be a beginner's question as I'm not that well versed in FPGA design.

What I basically have is a preprogrammed Lattice LFE5U-25F with an external memory and I don't have the source code of what is on the external memory.

So I decided to read out the data on the external memory and modify what I needed with a hex editor. The data I was modifying was a simple constant. However after writing the payload, the FPGA no longer boots. I tried different modifications but it behaves as if some sort of checksum has changed. I can't find anything relevant in the datasheet, so my question to you is:

Why does this approach not work? What is the underlying mechanism of this not working?

Comment: Then there probably is a checksum somewhere.

Comment: Well obviously. :D But where? On the memory chip - inside the bitstream data? Or is there some sort of way to burn it onto the fpga chip itself?

Comment: What did you edit? The main configuration ROM or some separate memory for settings?

Comment: You say the FPGA chip is pre-programmed, this means it is storing its "program" inside the FPGA chip itself, right? I ask because some low-cost FPGAs are like this, but the more advanced FPGAs require a separate memory chip which could be the one you're looking at.

Comment: @asdfex The main configuration ROM. So this is a USB capture card, I'm trying to modify it's EDID to have a different name and this seemed like the easiest way. Obviously it's not, but it got me curious what's happening.

The device consists of IT6801FN->LFE5U-25F->CYUSB3014 and an EEPROM. It seems that the FPGA programs the two other chips but as soon as I change the EDID in the ROM it stops initializing at all.

Comment: @user253751 I'm fairly certain this is the latter. The data has a header which makes me quite certain that it's the bitstream data and not some sort of variables table or smth like that.

Comment: Then, yes, there is probably a checksum in the bitstream. Corrupted bitstream could cause all sorts of problems (including permanent hardware damage) so it's sensible for it to have one. Good luck reverse-engineering it

Answer (score 1):

The content of the configuration Flash ROM for an FPGA is usually encrypted and equipped with checksums. For most devices the format of the data is not very well documented.

But, having an ECP5 FPGA you're on the lucky side: There is some documentation about the general file format in [Lattice TN 1260](https://www.latticesemi.com/%7E/media/LatticeSemi/Documents/ApplicationNotes/EH/TN1260.pdf). As you were able to find the string you searched for, we can also assume that the configuration has not been encrypted - otherwise any change would be impossible.

As it seems there is one checksum for each frame of data you need to identify and recalculate. The checksum is a plain CRC, so this can be calculated easily as soon as you have identified which bytes to include in the calculation.

There is also an open-source project ([Project Trellis](https://github.com/YosysHQ/prjtrellis)) with some tools and documentation of the internal structures of the ECP5 - their tools to generate and edit bitfiles might be of help for you.

Answer (score 0):

To first clarify what you're describing, you have a Lattice LFE5U-25F FPGA that holds its configuration file (CF) in an external Flash EPROM.

The CF is protected by a CRC and also is very difficult to reverse-engineer. That's one of the selling points of the FPGA: the underlying circuit is very difficult to extract from the CF. The manufacturer deliberately keeps the necessary details and documentation confidential, including the CRC algorithm.

So you can't do what you're trying to do, it'll be too difficult. You'll instead need to modify the source files and recompile it.

Comment: Ahaaa, so the checksum is on the EEPROM but stored in an unknown algorithm, i.e. somehow signed, correct? Not on the FPGA?

Comment: @TonyM You're too pessimistic. The general structure of ECP5 bitstreams is documented by Lattice themselves. And there's even an opensource reverse engineering project that was able to decipher every bit in the bitstream, Project Trellis.  Unless the bitstream of this proprietary board is ecrypted, of course...

Comment: @asdfex, probably not so much pessimistic as woefully out of date and pretty-much guesswork, then :-) Even as I wrote this in a bit of a hurry, I was thinking I ought to check it out carefully in the Lattice docs. Once you reply to this, I'll know you've seen it and I can delete the answer.